# Android - Graphical display not working in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

Not been able to find the answer to this

When ever I look at the graphical display for any of my XML files within eclipse, it only shows the text strings and not buttons or anything like that

The Error log reads 
error!
Unable to resolve drawable "C:\Program Files\android-sdk\platforms\android-10\data\res\drawable\btn_default.xml" in attribute "background"
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

I have tried changing the version of the api from drop down to no luck

Thanks for your time

Comment: Do you have a res\drawable\btn_default.xml in your project ?

Comment: nope. I created a new project and it created drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi and drawbale-mdpi. icon.png in each. Relative new to Android work

Comment: forgot to add, loading up into emulator the xml is displayed correctly

Comment: Do you have set Window->Preferences->Android->SDK Location?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a mismatch between your target SDK version and your Graphical Layout target, should be an easy fix.

If you don't know it off the top of your head, you can get your Android SDK version for your project from right-clicking on your project name, going to Properties, selecting "Android", and looking for the test in the "platform" column for the row with a checkmark.

Then in the Graphical Layout for your XML file, in the top right in between the Locale selector and the Create button is a drop-down for Android versions.  Change this to match the one for your project, and the errors should go away the graphical preview will render correctly.